# I have followed a tutorial on making controls for a fps game on unity. the controls work but if I leave the controls then I keep moving to the left

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrDZR.jpg)I have made controls for my character to move along the X axis. They seem to be working fine but my character keeps moving left and I'm not sure why or what I have missed.I have posted code from the two separate scripts

I have rechecked his code several times.I have checked to see if my arrow keys, numpad keys and WASD are sticking or any other.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    //gets a movement vector
    public void Move (Vector3 _velocity)
    {
        velocity = _velocity;
    }

    //run every physics iteration
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        PerformMovement();
    }

    //perform movement based on velocity variable
    void PerformMovement ()
    {
        if (velocity != Vector3.zero)
        {
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }

    }

}
```

And the controller:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerMotor))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]                //makes speed show up in inspector even if set to private
    private float speed = 5f;


    private PlayerMotor motor;
    void Start ()
    {
        motor = GetComponent<PlayerMotor>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Calculate movement velocity as a 3D vector
        float _xMov = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float _zMov = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Vector3 _movHorizontal = transform.right * _xMov;
        Vector3 _movVertical = transform.forward * _zMov;


        //final movement vector
        Vector3 _velocity = (_movHorizontal + _movVertical).normalized * speed;

        //apply movement
        motor.Move(_velocity);

    }
}
```

I expect 0 output when not pressing buttons but it seems to make me move to the left at speed of 5

Comment: Your code seems fine. Include a screenshot of your Input settings with the `Horizontal` axis expanded so we can see if that's configured properly.

Comment: do you mean in unity under project settings?

Comment: Yes, under **Project Settings**, in the **Input** section. Also, could you put a `Debug.Log("_xMov is: " + _xMov);` and tell us what it outputs? It might be best to edit your question and include the output there for easier reading.

Comment: sorry I just saw this now. I will try it out.. Apologies for the bad screenshot. I am working with two screens and I kinda messed up. Sorry I'm fairly new to c#. could you perhaps show me which line to add that Debug.Log. Sorry for being a pest. XD

Comment: _xMov is: -0,1285403
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets/PlayerController.cs:21)

BoxColliders does not support negative scale or size.
The effective box size has been forced positive and is likely to give unexpected collision geometry.
If you absolutely need to use negative scaling you can use the convex MeshCollider. Scene hierarchy path "Player/Camera/Gun/Cube"

I'll edit my question as well but here is what I get in the console. I forgot about the box collider report which I will add as well. I hope this provides clarity.

Comment: It looks like you may have a controller connected and reporting a slight movement in one direction. Try using `Input.GetAxis` instead of `Input.GetAxisRaw` to let Unity handle deadzone detection.

Comment: hahahaha thank you so so much I completely forgot about my controller that I have plugged in. thank you so so much once again. Is there any way I can give you a thumbs up or a recommendation. I'm very new to stack overflow XD.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to go ahead and write up an answer and you can go ahead and click the grey checkmark on it when its up to mark it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a controller connected and reporting a slight movement in one direction. Use `Input.GetAxis` instead of `Input.GetAxisRaw` to let Unity handle deadzone detection. This way, nearly neutral inputs will be treated as neutral inputs.

```
void Update()
{
    //Calculate movement velocity as a 3D vector
    float _xMov = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float _zMov = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 _movHorizontal = transform.right * _xMov;
    Vector3 _movVertical = transform.forward * _zMov;


    //final movement vector
    Vector3 _velocity = (_movHorizontal + _movVertical).normalized * speed;

    //apply movement
    motor.Move(_velocity);

}
```